# Using ng-switch to populate a table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dynamic, html-table

I'm using a Angular.js on the front end to populate a table. I want to use ng-switch to display only data that has specific data in one column, for example only show ‘week 1’ data from a list of a NFL schedule, where one column in the data is Weeks.

So right now this code doesn't show anything in the table. If anyone could help explain this it would be greatly appreciated. Maybe I should be using ng-if ? Maybe I should have a button to press to show week 1, week 2 etc.. What's the best solution for this type of situation?

Here's the controller..

```
// #########################
// Predictions Controller
// #########################
BLV_app.controller('PredictionsController', function($scope, PredictionsFactory, $routeParams) {
  PredictionsFactory.getPredictions(function(data) {
        $scope.predictions = data;
  });
});
```

Here's the factory..

```
// ---------------------------
// Prediction Factory
// ---------------------------
BLV_app.factory('PredictionsFactory', function($http) {
  var factory = {};
  var predictions = [];
  factory.getPredictions = function(callback) {
    $http.get('/predictions').success(function(output) {
        predictions = output;
        console.log("prediction factory", predictions);
        callback(output);
      });
    };
  return factory;
});
```

Here's the html..

```
     <table class="table-striped" id="table-style">
            <thead id="table-header">
                <tr>
                    <th class="text-center">HomeTeam</th>
                    <th class="text-center">AwayTeam</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Prediction</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Result</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody ng-repeat="predict in predictions" >
              <div ng-model="predict.Week"></div>
                <tr ng-switch="predict.Week">
                  <div ng-switch-when="1">
                    <td ng-if="$odd" style="background-color:#f1f1f1">{{ predict.HomeTeam }}</td>
                    <td ng-if="$even">{{ predict.HomeTeam }}</td>
                    <td ng-if="$odd" style="background-color:#f1f1f1">{{ predict.AwayTeam }}</td>
                    <td ng-if="$even">{{ predict.AwayTeam }}</td>
                    <td ng-if="$odd" style="background-color:#f1f1f1">{{ predict.Prediction }}</td>
                    <td ng-if="$even">{{ predict.Prediction }}</td>
                    <td ng-if="$odd" style="background-color:#f1f1f1">{{ predict.Result }}</td>
                    <td ng-if="$even">{{ predict.Result }}</td>
                  </div>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Comment: What is the definition of `PredictionsFactory.getPredictions`?

Comment: Hi @webDeveloper 101 can you provide jsfiddle link so it will be easy solve your issue

Comment: if i take out all the ng-switch statements and extra div's it shows all the data from every week on the table.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is something wrong with `ng-repeat` and `ng-switch` when binding to elements like `tbody` and `td`. Replace them with `div` and `li` makes it working properly: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u0zo21tx/4/).

```
<div ng-repeat="predict in predictions">
    <div ng-model="predict.id"></div>
    <div ng-switch="predict.id">
    <div ng-switch-when="1">
        <li ng-if="$odd" style="background-color:#f1f1f1">{{ predict.name }}</li>
    ......
```

Changing from `<div ng-repeat="predict in predictions">` to `<tbody ng-repeat="predict in predictions">` makes it not working: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u0zo21tx/3/).

In [`ng-repeat` docs](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.2/docs/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) and [`ng-switch` docs](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.2/docs/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch), it says:

```
Usage
as attribute:
<ANY
  ng-repeat="">
...
</ANY>
```

But obviously they cannot be used on **ANY** elements.